# Run database query in datastage with no inputs or outputs

Tags: datastage

Relatively new to datastage, quite possibly a stupid question.

From datastage, I want to run a database query against a SQL Server database. The query is a delete query with a hardcoded WHERE clause (not my decision).

What I cannot figure out is how to run a query through the ODBC connector without inputs or outputs. If I don't link the connector to either an input or output, the 'Usage' section of the ODBC connector does not appear.

Is it possible to make the 'Usage' section appear without linking inputs/outputs? If not, is there another alternative in datastage to accomplishing what I have described?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DataStage only writes to a database when data comes from a link.

What you can do is :

- Put a Row Generator Stage in your Job and configure it to generate one row (with one column)
- Link that Stage to your ODBC database target
- Put your static query on the link

You don't have to use data on the generated row, it's just necessary to trigger action on the target.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue, and now achieved it by designing the job as below,

***Row_generator -> Transformer -> copy_stage -> DB_connector***

**Row_generator**- define a column to generate(need not map to output in transformer stage)

**Transformer** - Add an output column say "dummy" and hard code it as "1"
and RCP should be unchecked.

**copy_stage** - Dont map anything to the output link, just keep **RCP enabled**.

**DB_connector** - in the query box , mention delete statement as
" delete from #Schema#.#Table# where **1=orchestrate.dummy**"

In the above query we are using the *condition 1=orchestrate.dummy* which is always TRUE.
Let me know if it works !! Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

1. Connect the ODBC connector stage to a copy stage
2. Code a dummy select query ( Oracle , you can use "select 1 as dummy from dual")
3. Give the  dummy col name in the columns with with a datatype
4. Plug in your Delete query in Before or After SQL of the ODBC connector stage

I have production jobs running with the same requirement . Should work as smooth as wine :)

Answer (score 0):

1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[Security No], Customer.DOB, Customer.IDNo, Customer.ContactNumber, Customer.cnu' at line 1